# Logical Debunking of Alien Abduction/Encounters

Tags: life, astrobiology

I was just watching a story on TV about a man who tells a story of abduction (your basic run-of-the-mill abduction story) and was thinking about how every time someone explains these stories, the aliens have legs and arms and are generally upright beings similar to humans.

First off, the odds of a planet being similar to Earth and possible to sustain life in a human form are pretty rare (I know that it's not impossible by any means, particularly with the billions and billions of planets out there, but still slim nonetheless). Second, on top of that, the added odds of life evolving to the point where it develops a similar intelligence and body structure have to be even more astronomically rare. And on top of that, them making contact with our planet as opposed to any other planet adds less odds.

Now obviously you can tell I don't believe any of these abduction/alien encounter stories but I've never heard anyone attempt to debunk them in this way (or at least present a logical probability of it happening). Has anyone heard of this kind of explanation of why the odds are so slim of this ever happening to anyone? If not, anyone have a ballpark figure? I understand the possibility is there (even if it is in the 1 in 1 trillion+) but come on now...

Perhaps this is better suited for the skeptics forum but I figure you all have more of a scientific background that would help rationally explain this. I'm sorry if I'm posting in the wrong place, just let me know and I can move it. Thanks everyone!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about alien abduction. Perhaps skeptics.stackexchange.com is a better site for this question.

Comment: Well it's not really about abduction, it's more about the probability of life in the universe similar to ours?

Comment: VTC, There is some potential to clean this question up to bring it into scope but as written the off topic content distracts from anything that may be in scope here.

Comment: *"If not, anyone have a ballpark figure?"*  Saner heads cannot even come up with a ball-park figure of the end result of the [Drake Equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drake_equation#Range_of_values).  ..Unless you consider some value between 8*10^-20 and 36.4 million to be 'ball-park'.

Comment: It's IMO a reasonable question to ask, but off-topic here as it does not pertain to [space.se] as per our [About]. Closing as off-topic and have asked [skeptics.se] moderators, if they're OK with migration. Please don't cross-post! We'll migrate it for you to a more suitable [se] site once that is established. Thanks!

Comment: OK update: [Skeptics.SE] mods consider the question too speculative and doesn't have a definitive answer. Migration (after I recieved word from one of their mods that it might be salvageable) was [rejected](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/22070/logical-debunking-of-alien-abduction-encounters) by their reviewers and the question put on hold as off-topic. If you could [edit] it to narrow it down to something more specific and make it answerable without speculation and opinions, that would be great.

Comment: I think the question spans subject areas. Speculation on extraterrestrial life is part of astronomy. Searching for extraterrestrial life is part of space exploration, as is the question of what sort of life we might encounter. This would include the question of plausibility of visits to Earth by hypothesized extraterrestrials. I think the only intersection with "skeptics" would be in discussion of specific "alien encounter" claims.

Comment: @MxmastaMills - Would be on-topic on [Aliens](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/80090/aliens) proposal I guess.

Comment: Some well-founded lines of reasoning suggest that the universe is teeming with life - that there could well be billions of planets in our own galaxy harboring life, and there could be thousands or even millions of civilizations out there. The problem is the vast distances which must be traversed between stars, and even the nearest likely candidates are far too far away for practical travel, making alien visits to Earth theoretically possible but extremely, extremely unlikely.

Answer (score 3):

Before I answer this I want to say I don't believe any of the alien abduction stories either.

Now that being said, the reason no one debunks them using statistics of likelihood evolution of life etc., is [Drake's equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drake_equation). Put simply Drakes equation calculates the probability of life on other planets, and shows that irrespective of what coefficients you use for probability that: stars have planets, planets are in the goldilocks zone, life evolves etc., you're pretty much guaranteed that there is other life out there. Mainly because of the ridiculously high number of stars.

For the second logical debunking method: so there's life out there but why would it look like us? It almost certainly wouldn't look exactly like us, but there is a theory that due the the process of evolution the species that survives to evolve into the most intelligent (e.g. humans) will likely have similar appearance, this is called [parallel evolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_evolution). For example if we make the assumption that the alien brain will be physically similar to ours, then it'll likely need to be around the same size. It also logical that the brain will have any 'eyes', 'ears' etc. close to it to allow for faster data transfer to the brain so it can make quicker decisions about the environment. There's [evidence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_evolution#Examples) of this type of parallel evolution on our planet so this is a reasonably solid argument.

As for why they would pick out planet to visit, we've been [sending out radio waves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arecibo_message) for some time now. We also have a lot of objects in orbit around the planet. Lets not delve into the sci-fi of what hardware and science the aliens have, but it's easy to say they're advanced enough to 'find' us.

So that's the reason why these theories aren't debunked off the cuff. However there is some recent discussion about the [utility of drakes equation](http://www.technologyreview.com/view/424795/probability-of-et-life-arbitrarily-small-say-astrobiologists/), and applying Bayesian maths shows the likelihood to be much lower than expected especially this early on in the universe. There's also some [fundamental principals of physics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_of_light) which we haven't yet managed to break, that would massively increase the travel time for these aliens or make it impossible for them to have heard our radio waves unless they were already quite close. Other reasons against it become almost as sci-fi as the alien abductions themselves, so I wont go any further.

Comment: Perhaps splitting hairs, but... instead of citing parallel evolution, it might be more appropriate to cite convergent evolution as regards the argument to not discount the possibility of approximately humanoid forms when speculating on spacefaring extraterrestrials. Maybe a subtle distinction, but it more clearly expresses the notion of similar traits appearing in species with no relevant common ancestor. The classic example being winged flight appearing independently in birds, bats, pterosaurs, and insects.

Comment: Good point! I'll edit the question when I have time later, or you can if you'd prefer.